A user is removing tags from questions, that I edited
I'm editing questions from my past, and they become active on the tags. I do a substantial edits, so the tags editing is included to the finil revision. But BalusC is sitting on the active tag and removing questions from tags, by editing them, making non-sens comments like "Not JSP problem; No Java SE problem, etc.". I'm sure the questions I edited should contain tags, and that tags are relevant to the context of the question. Just editing tags is not a substantial edit and it is a violation of rules of SO. I tried to rollback my edits, but the offender persists on its own. I don't need to envolve one or more rollback war with the offender, but I need my questions be consistent and accurately tagged that I provided, but BalusC is conflicting with my intentions. Why should I make concessions? I have flagged the question which is affected. Also this behaviour of BalusC is continues on every active question . He just removing tags and finds duplicates with his answered posts. I don't care if he is removing tags from questions that he had answered , but I am trying to draw attention to questions that I had answered and didn't get any sufficient reputation for my answers.
This is an example of such questions:

How to use `if` condition in JSP and run JavaScript function?

This is my flag and a moderator answer:

Why BalusC is removing tags from questions I have edited? It is not substantial editing just remove tags. – Roman C 3 hours ago 
Declined - they removed [javascript] because this question has nothing to do with Javascript

It is not true, the question has to do with JavaScript, to call a JS function which OP is posted.
Can anyone help me?

"Just editing tags is not a substantial edit and it is a violation of rules of SO" - I disagree. Ensuring a question is correctly tagged is vital for discoverability. I'm not saying that the user's edits were correct - I don't have enough SME to judge that - but your assessment of tag-only edits in general is definitely incorrect.

Tags should be what the question is about, not what it's using. This is an nuanced, and often missed, distinction. I admit, I know nothing about the languages involved here, however, if I am understanding the problem correctly, the question isn't about the JavaScript itself, but how to have a jsp if statement execute; yes there is JavaScript in the question, but that isn't what the question about.

@ThomA The question is about js function which OP wants to call from the code which was posted.

If I were to give an example I'm more familiar with, I often see/saw questions tagged with [[tag:sql-server]] (and possibly even [[tag:SQL]]) for questions about C#, because SQL Server was the database backend the asker was using. Although there's code using SQL Server and defining a statement to be run against it, said SQL was completely unrelated to the actual problem (the entire thing could have an [mre] made without SQL (Server) involved). As such, in those scenarios, I often removed the [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:SQL]] tags; the scenario here appears to be similar.

@ThomA If your example use c# to connect to the SQL server and submit SQL queries to persist data, then why it is not about SQL?

In general, I think publicly railing against a user by name is poor form. In other posts here on Meta, even users who feel persecuted by another user refer to them as "the user", "a moderator", etc., even when the target is obvious. I think this tiny level of abstraction is beneficial to de-personalize the issue.

@RomanC Because the question itself is not about SQL, it just arose in a situation where SQL was also being used. There are situations where a user -- generally a beginner -- genuinely doesn't understand the distinction between SQL and C#; editing tags in situations like this isn't to punish the asker, it's to help them by making the site more efficient for people finding questions to answer.

It doesn't look like they are specifically targeting your edits, they are probably just watching some specific tags from what I see in their activity tab. For the most part their edits do seem to make a bit of sense to me (Note: I am not an SME in the tags they are editing)

@RomanC Are you asking for the edit of the specific linked question why the [tag:javascript] tag was removed? It is unclear if you want to talk about that specific edit or about editing tags in general. Rewrite the question (maybe even tag it with specific-question) to make the discussion clear.

@Progman It is not specific, I have posted only one example of such behaviour. BalusC is removing continuously tags like [Java], [JSP], [servlets], and even [struts2] questions. He thinks about their own vision of tag relevance. A lot of questions that I have answered are suffered of such edits.

"He thinks about their own vision of tag relevance." Aren't you doing the exact same thing, @RomanC?

@Cerbrus Should I do the same thing? What do you mean?

No, I'm saying that you're thinking about your own version of tag relevance, now. A version which might not be correct.

@Sneftel All questions that are codded in Java are tagged as [java], but these questions are not about Java, they just used Java for code. How would we treat the [Java] tag relevance. If it is not about Java as programming language, then why not to remove [java] tag from them?

@RomanC Few tags have exact rules about where they're meant to be used or not used; tagging and untagging is based on users' estimation of which tags will get the appropriate people to see the question, while avoiding clogging up a tag with questions which people watching that tag won't have any expertise or interest in.

@Sneftel Why the few tags, and what is BalusC is doing - narrowing the user' estimation by removing certain tags from them.

"I am trying to draw attention to questions that I had answered and didn't get any sufficient reputation for my answers." Sorry, are you suggesting you think tags affect how much reputation you get from upvotes or something?

@RomanC I didn't understand what you said there. What does it mean to "narrow the user' estimation"? What user? And what do you mean by "Why the few tags"?

@Sneftel It means that less users will see the question. Because users are watching only tags they choose according their interests. The user is anyone you, me, BalusC, etc., everyone have a right to put a tag on the question they answered. Other questions has less interest for answerer. A few tags like [java] did you mean are general to all problems.

On the other hand, if the tag isn't relevant to the main thrust of the question, attracting those extra eyes is usually a negative. Those new eyes probably do not care. For example, C++ code that calls a C DLL probably shouldn't tag C unless the problem is with the interaction between C and C++; otherwise, we need to tag a lot more C, and probably fortran, than we do and it won't help anyone.

"The user is anyone you, me, BalusC, etc., everyone have a right to put a tag on the question they answered." Everyone with 2k reputation has a right (more accurately, a privilege) to change the tags on any question, and everyone below that has a right to propose a tag change. But the changes that will ultimately be accepted are the ones that are in accordance with policy, and not because any specific person wants them.

@user4581301 In the above example the JavaScript code is wrapped into JSP and it should be executed when a JSP page is displayed. It is not a pure JavaScript code, but a shpagetty code, so why JavaScript is removed. In JSP world there's no such thing as alert()? So, requires people who knows both JSP and JavaScript, missing one of them in the tag results as negative, that you mentioned.

@RomanC But do you actually need to know what alert() does to answer the question? Would attracting JavaScript experts to the question be useful at all? (other than to get you more upvotes, because that is very much not the purpose of tags)

@JohnMontgomery The expert should expertize both JSP and JavaScript to answer this question. And it doesn't matter how much upvotes you receive. Compared to BalusC much less. The answer even is not accepted, and have views only.

I don't see what JavaScript knowledge is needed to answer the question. The scenario could have easily been to conditionally generate CSS or HTML. Or even just plain text. The solution is the same with all three. Because the solution only needs to describe how to properly do the conditional statement in JSP (which also needs Java code to be done). Your answer shows zero JavaScript outside what was already in the question - neither code, nor explanation how something works, nor documentation, nor any mention of JavaScript.

Just to cure the twitch in my eye: no it is not actually necessary to do Java code in JSPs, JSTL was invented long ago to do it in a Java-less templating style. JSPs are old, putting Java code in JSPs is software archaeology.

@Gimby Nobody restricts you to do so, and this question is not about it.

From what I can see, BalusC generally correctly removes superfluous or even unrelated tags from questions.
Basically, he's not doing anything wrong.
Just because there's some code of a certain language in a question, doesn't necessarily mean that that code is the problem, or even relevant to the answer.
Looking at your last 2 edits involving tag changes, however:

I would suggest not adding generic tags like "methods" and "configuration" to questions.
They don't convey any meaningful information, and frankly, should probably be burninated.

"Just because there's some code of a certain language in a question, doesn't necessarily mean that that code is the problem, or even relevant to the answer." the litmus test should be "Will an expert in  help me here?". I know JS. I also know Java. The former doesn't help me at all. The latter helps a bit. However, I can't really answer that question meaningfully without knowing about the JSP side of things.

This is what is commented above, if the question about methods, then it should be tagged as methods, if the question has a problem with the configuration then added missing tags. The tag's list has limited to 5 tags, so you can't add more than 5 related tags to the question.

@VLAZ generally that is the litmus test, but overall I think the site works better if questions have at least one tag that is a programming language (or else something like [tag:language-agnostic] where applicable).

@RomanC just bacause you can add 5 tags, doesn't mean a question has to have 5 tags. Those tags you added are completely useless. There are no "Methods" or "Configuration" subject matter experts. Those tags are meaningless.


It is not true, the question has to do with JavaScript, to call a JS function which OP is posted.
Can anyone help me?

If you accept "help" in the form of an explanation of why you are wrong, then yes.
The question clearly does not have to do with JavaScript. Putting JavaScript code in a question doesn't make it a JavaScript question.
How do you know, in this case? Because the JavaScript code could be anything, for any purpose, and the question wouldn't change. The question is about how to make JSP conditionally include code within the JavaScript function. What that function actually does is completely irrelevant to the question being asked. It's only shown there for demonstration purposes.
Notice how the java tag that you added 10 years ago was not removed from this question, because it is a Java question (noting well that the languages Java and JavaScript have nothing at all to do with each other). We know this even though there is not any complete Java code (just a fragment of JSP, following Java syntax) in the question. How?
Because the question is about using JSP to do something. JSP is a Java technology. Answering the question with code would require writing Java code. But it would not require writing JavaScript code. In your answer, where you replaced if (String "contact"=request.getParameter("contact");) with String contact; if ((contact=request.getParameter("contact")) != null, fundamentally you were writing Java, not JavaScript. (In JavaScript, String is a function, and variable declarations don't use a typename.) The code where the problem occurs isn't JavaScript; it's essentially Java embedded within a Java templating language that will produce JavaScript output. (The code sent to the client won't contain these <%if ... %> "tags", and wouldn't know what to do with them if they were.)

Just editing tags is not a substantial edit and it is a violation of rules of SO.

This is simply incorrect. First off, there is no rule against making "insubstantial" edits - it's simply a reason why edits that require review, from users below 2000 reputation, might be declined. Second, a specific interface is provided for editing just the tags, exactly so that users with unilateral editing privileges can apply these fixes more efficiently. Retagging is an important service that helps curate the site; and the only reasons for declining insubstantial edits are specific to the fact that lower-rep users' edits need to be reviewed.

I tried to rollback my edits, but the offender persists on its own. I don't need to envolve one or more rollback war with the offender, but I need my questions be consistent and accurately tagged that I provided, but BalusC is conflicting with my intentions. Why should I make concessions?

Because maintaining the site is a community effort and your "intentions" are not privileged. Policy is the result of a consensus understanding by the community of what will give the best results in the long run. Of course, moderators also play a key role in settling disputes. In this case, a moderator quickly found that the tags you consider "accurate" are not - even though moderators are not expected to be subject matter experts.

He just removing tags and finds duplicates with his answered posts.

Finding duplicates, too, is useful and noble. The goal of the site is to serve as a useful repository of information, as described in the tour; the best answers should therefore appear on the best possible version of the question, and no answers should be posted on other versions, but instead they should directly link future viewers to the reference version. That way, the thousands or even millions of people who check the site later can get the best answer directly, even if they use slightly different language in their search.

I don't care if he is removing tags from questions that he had answered , but I am trying to draw attention to questions that I had answered and didn't get any sufficient reputation for my answers.

You don't get to decide how much reputation is "sufficient" for your answers. If anything, you are telling us now that you add tags to a question to try to make it more important, so that people will give you more reputation, instead of trying to make the site better organized. That is abusive and misunderstands how Stack Overflow works. You already have enough reputation needed for all the privileges available on the site, so there is no good reason to compete for more.
